# Mixing ctypes and python classes in _fields_

Tags: python, gstreamer, ctypes, gobject

I am trying to create a ctypes wrapper for a struct that uses gobject.

The struct is defined as follows:

```
struct GstMetaStruc
{
    GstMeta meta;

    GstStructure* structure;
};
```

GstMeta has an existing introspection wrapper that offers me accress to the base meta object.

My current, wrong approach looks like this:

```
import ctypes
import gi

gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst

class TcamMeta(ctypes.Structure):
    """

    """
    _fields_ = [("meta", Gst.Meta),
                ("structure", ctypes.POINTER(Gst.Structure))]
```

Is it possible to mix ctype definitions with existing python wrapper classes?
Are there better approaches to define python classes for derived types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - Structures and unions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) states (**emphasis** is mine):

> Structures and unions must derive from the [Structure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure) and [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Union) base classes which are defined in the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module. Each subclass must define a *_fields_* attribute. *_fields_* must be a list of *2-tuples*, containing a *field name* and a *field type*.
>
> **The field type must be a [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) type like [c_int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int), or any other derived [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) type: structure, union, array, pointer**.

The *_fields_* members are implemented as *descriptors*, meaning that they are "special" (compared to a regular class member). As a consequence, some checks are performed when declaring the structure.

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>> class A: pass
> ...
> >>> class Stru0(ct.Structure): pass
> ...
> >>> class Stru1(ct.Structure): _fields_ = [("c", Stru0)]
> ...
> >>> class Stru1(ct.Structure): _fields_ = [("c", ct.c_float)]
> ...
> >>> class Stru1(ct.Structure): _fields_ = [("c", int)]
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: second item in _fields_ tuple (index 0) must be a C type
> >>> class Stru1(ct.Structure): _fields_ = [("c", A)]
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: second item in _fields_ tuple (index 0) must be a C type
> ```

So, if you didn't get a *TypeError*, you're probably *OK*. But briefly looking at *PyGObject* examples, you shouldn't be in the situation requiring this.